# KO "click" binding won't work for mobile device responsive

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create a responsive one page web application. On clicking the list of items on the side bar you the markers and on the map should animate and display info window. **It seems to be working perfect on normal browser layout but when I toggle display to smaller screens or on a mobile device, The click function does not work.** The logic seems to be correct. Please help me understand where I am going wrong and what I should do. Thank you.

```
     <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
         <script src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
        </head>

       <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
               <h1 class="center" > Chennai City Culture </h1>

                <div class="input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12" >
                  <input id="text-search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter here" data-bind="textInput: query">
                </div>

                <div class= "list-box" data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-item"data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.setLoc"></a>
                    <hr>
                </div>

             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-16 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                 <div id="map">
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBf9eFadPLrD3QIQT7ygrYN8aRO5YuAUyE&callback=initMap" onerror="error()">
        </script>

       </body>
      </html>
```

JS:

```
        function appViewModel(){
      var self = this;
      this.query = ko.observable('');

      this.locationArray = ko.observableArray([]);
      locations.forEach(function(item){
        self.locationArray().push(item);
      });

      self.setLoc = function(clickedLoc) {
        var clickedData = clickedLoc.marker;
        google.maps.event.trigger(clickedData, 'click');
      };

      self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function(){
        var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();

        if(!filter){

          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              if (locations[i].marker) //checks to see that markers exist
              locations[i].marker.setVisible(true);
          }
          return self.locationArray();
        }
        return this.locationArray().filter(function (item){

          var passedFilter = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
          item.marker.setVisible(passedFilter);
          return passedFilter;
        });
      }, self);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

click events aren't the same as touch events; try including a library like touchpunch that will handle those events for you for mobile devices. I had the same issue with a KO app I was building and that seemed to solve it.

Comment: The click event is not working for smaller screens as well. Please help me understand what is going wrong. Thank you

Comment: your script file is throwing errors... locations is not defined (on line 6). Also your initMap callback doesn't seem to exist... are you sure you posted the correct JS file?

Comment: I updated only the .computed function thinking there must be some logical error in the code.

Here is the link to my github with updated changes. https://github.com/AkankshiSamanta/neighborhood-map